# compare django variable with angular variable

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I am using django backend and angular for frontend. Now i am facing an issue which is i need to compare a variable value which comes from django view with another variable value which comes from angular. i m doing this following simple way but it is not working. please suggest how to do this.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% if item.employee_id == {% verbatim %}{{ interview._source.employee.id }}{% endverbatim %}  %}
            something here
    {% else %}
        something here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, I don't think its possible  to compare the angularjs variable with a Django variable in the Django template.

This is because **all the variables and template tags are computed on the server side while angularjs is rendered on the client side.**

You won't have access to the angularjs variable until that variable is generated on the client side.

**Solution:**

A possible solution is to calculate and compare the variable on the server side in the Django code i.e. move the comparison logic to Django code if possible.

Comment: Is there no any other option to do this easily??

Comment: I don't think there is an option to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap your logic around. There is **no possible way** for Django templates to be aware of Angular variables, and it really should be clear why.

Instead, you'll need to output everything you need in the template, and use Angular code to do the comparison.